# Programmatically list all cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, bdd

Is there any way to programmatically list all cucumber scenarios?  Something like 
    Cucumber.scenarios would be great.
I am trying to build a tool on top of cucumber and listing scenarios is very important.  The alternative  is to run all scenarios, grab each scenario in the after hook and store somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To list the scenarios in Cucumber you can use the `-d` switch on command line.
Also you can combine with `-f` for specifying the output format.

If you want integrate the loading and parsing the .feature files you will need to take a look at the source code of cucumber and try to replicate when you cannot use the implementation.

Since this is a "custom" implementation and you don't provide any code, this is the far as I can go to help you.